# Ruby: regex to remove tags if attributes don't have allowed values

Tags: ruby, regex

I have such a text:

```
<a href="http://www.i-am-hacker.com/blah">click here!</a>blah-blah-some-text-here-blah<a href="http://www.some-good-website.com/blah">click here!</a>
```

What's the correct way to remove all `<a></a>` tags (end everything inside them) if `<a href=` does **NOT** have `some-good-website`?

Comment: is a non-regex solution also possible? i think it might be easier using something like nokogiri.

Comment: Yes, it's also possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution using [Nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

TEST =  '<a href="http://www.i-am-hacker.com/blah">click here!</a>blah-blah-some-text-here-blah<a href="http://www.some-good-website.com/blah">click here!</a>'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(TEST)
links = page.css("a") # parse all <a></a> elements from content
links.each do |link|
    if link['href'] =~ /http:\/\/www\.i-am-hacker\.com\/blah/
        link.remove
    end
end
puts page # output content for debugging
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>blah-blah-some-text-here-blah<a href="http://www.some-good-website.com/blah">click here!</a>
</body></html>
```

**Useful resource:** http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/
This site helped me a lot understanding how to use nokogiri

---

If you need to install [nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/), you can do that by using the following command:

```
gem install nokogiri
```